# How do I change the default user model?

Tags: django

How do I change the default model of a user?

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

default settings path **django.conf.global_settings**

**global_settings.py**  file:

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/conf/global_settings.py#L508

so **settings.py** add code line

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myuserapp.MyUser'
```

create MyUser models.